# Force-update the meta variable first set using `var [ meta, setMeta = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );`

Tags: javascript, post-meta, block-editor, react

Context: I've got a plugin that triggers some actions when a post is saved, like contact an external API and save the result as a custom field. All of this happens in the background, using PHP and the `transition_post_status` hook. So far so good.

Inside the Gutenberg editor, I have a sidebar panel where I run, among other things, `var [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' )`, which allows me to display the custom field if it exists (from when the post was previously saved).

Now, what I'm after is the following: For a brand-new post, I want to fetch this field a second or two after the post was saved and display it in said panel.

I have the listener for this figured out, the timeout in place. I can rerender the "block" fine by "changing state." But what I just can't figure out is how to get the latest and greatest post meta.

No matter what I do, `meta` just contains the old post meta (like, for a brand-new post, that specific field did not exist), even if in the background the custom field has changed (was added).

As mentioned, I've tried to force a rerender using `useState()`; this works but the `meta` is not updated, as if it's cached in the browser. I have no idea if or how this "cache" can be invalidated.

What I have sort of tried: Wrap the `useEntityProp()` call in `useEffect()` with a `refresh` "stateful" (is that what it's called?) variable as a dependency. Not sure if this is the right direction at all; I'm afraid my React knowledge is lacking, as I can't get it to run without errors.

Some idea of the current code:

```
registerPlugin( 'my-custom-panel', {
    render: function( props ) {
        var postId   = useSelect( ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostId(), [] );
        var postType = useSelect( ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(), [] );

        var [ meta, setMeta ]       = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );
        var [ refresh, setRefresh ] = useState( false );

        var wasSavingPost     = data.select( 'core/editor' ).isSavingPost();
        var wasAutosavingPost = data.select( 'core/editor' ).isAutosavingPost();

        wp.data.subscribe( () => {
            var isSavingPost     = data.select( 'core/editor' ).isSavingPost();
            var isAutosavingPost = data.select( 'core/editor' ).isAutosavingPost();

            var shouldRefresh = wasSavingPost && ! wasAutosavingPost && ! isSavingPost && ( 'publish' === data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'status' ) );

            wasSavingPost     = isSavingPost;
            wasAutosavingPost = isAutosavingPost;

            if ( shouldRefresh ) {
                setTimeout( () => {
                    setRefresh( ! refresh ); // This forces the panel to update, but not `meta`.
                }, 2000 );
            }
        } );

        return el( PluginDocumentSettingPanel, {
            // And so on ...
```

What I was thinking to add:

```
useEffect( () => {
    // Somehow update `meta`, but how??
    // Can't just do `[ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );` once more, as that produces an error.
    // So, how can I trigger a new API call and get the latest and greatest `meta`?
}, [refresh] );
```

For clarity: I'm not trying to update anything **from** the editor, like using `setMeta` or similar. I want to use *one of the built-in APIs*, preferably, to refetch the latest and greatest post meta.

I could use a custom API endpoint for this, but that comes with quite a bit of overhead. Surely someone that knows Gutenberg better than I do knows of a way to simply do this ...

Comment: "*fetch this field a second or two after the post was saved*" - by "saved", did you mean after publishing the post, i.e. when the post status is changed to `publish`? "*using PHP and the `transition_post_status` hook*" - can you include your code, and also your complete JS code, more specifically the `return el( PluginDocumentSettingPanel, ... )` part?

Comment: You should also include the steps which can help us reproduce the issue, and also all relevant code that can help us help you further. Because depending on your PHP code, you don't actually need to complicate your JS code, i.e. you could simply read from the `meta` object.